# Memory Leakage due to HashMap

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, jprofiler

I am facing memory leakage because of `HashMap` in my code. When I first login to the application this `HashMap` populate and I use this `Map` to cache some data.

I used this cached Data several places in my application.

Its size grows continuously after Login when nothing is running in the application.
The size decreases only in the situation when the garbage collector is called automatically or I call that.

But after that it again starts increasing. It is a memory leak for sure but how can I avoid it?

My profiler also showing `ResultSet.getString()` and `Statement.execute()` as the hotspot memory allocation. these methods used to populate this cache.

Is the memory leak there because of these methods? I have close the DB Connection in finally block.

Why it is still showing me these methods?

Comment: How can it possibly be a memory leak when the garbage collector collects the memory in question?

Comment: I dont know but I notice that after GC called the memory used decreased but after some time it again increased rapidly when nothing is running in my application... Isn't it memory leak??

Comment: You don't need to use more than one question mark to indicate a question. `??` does not make it "more" of a question than `?` does. And pelase don't make half your question **bold**. Likewise, `code markup` should only be used for actual *code*. Not just for works you want to emphasize. Follow those rules to make it easier for others to read your question. Thanks

Comment: Without more detail, how can we help you? If you think it's a "leak" and it is there because of the caching, don't cache(?) If you need to cache, then put up with the garbage collector doing what it's supposed to do. Like jalf says, if the GC is doing it's job, there is no leak.

Comment: No, usually, a memory leak means that memory "gets lost", so that it **does not** get freed again. You simply have something that uses up memory. It's not a leak, because the memory is freed as expected by the GC

Comment: Thank you jalf for edit. Ok its not a memory leak but my CPU taking lots of memory then expected in the above two methods which are used to retrieve data from DataBase and populate the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments above explain, this does not sound like a memory leak.

In a java application, the JVM will create objects and use up memory. As time goes on, some of the objects will go out of scope (become eligible for garbage-collection) but until the next collection happens, they will still be in the heap, 'using up memory'. This is not a problem, it is how java works. When the JVM decides it needs to free up memory, it will run a collection and the used memory should drop.

Should you care about what you are seeing? I can think of two reasons you should and one you why shouldn't. If your garbage-collections free up enough memory for the application keep running, the collections do not affect performance and you are a busy person with other things to do, then I see no reason why you should care.

If however, you are worried that you do not understand how the application works in detail, or you have a reason why "so much memory" is an issue (you will want to run the application with even more data in future, or will want to run it with less heap assigned in future), then you may want to investigate.

If the memory is being used up when the application is doing nothing, then I would focus on that. What is it really doing when it is doing 'nothing'? I bet it's doing 'something'

Comment: By doing nothing I meant that I've successfully logged into the system, cache successfully populated but then when I wait for sometime and see again the memory is still growing.